# PHP Float val and double not working properly on my server

Tags: php, floating-point

I had a running project in PHP after migrating it to a new Godaddy server I am facing an issue with float value.

Like if I use `floatval` to a number string, it outputs a bigger floating number:

`floatval('155.55')` the expected output is 155.55, but the output is 155.55000000000001136868377216160297393798828125

I don't have any idea what's wrong with the server I am using if anyone can suggest me if there is some PHP setting I have to change and If I need to install a package to the server or anything like that, help me to solve the issue.

Comment: it's working fine what was an exact issue?